# On Linux, how to play an image sequency with audio?

Tags: linux, command-line, audio, images, mpv

I want to view an image sequence playing with external audio simultaneously.

I'm currently using `mpv "mf://*.jpg" -mf-fps X` to play sequences. Not sure how to define audio stream, yet.

I'm aware of merging the two formats with something like `ffmpeg`, however; I'd like to skip that part.

Preferably, I'd like to use FOSS software.

I've stumbled upon [DJV](https://github.com/darbyjohnston/DJV) developer mentioning working on audio support in [this thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/djv/discussion/404108/thread/b6be9d90/) (the ticket being [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/djv/feature-requests/57/)), thought I haven't been able to spot any implementation in the software, yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `mpv`, use one of the `--audio-file=<file>` / `--audio-files=<files>` options.

From `man mpv`:

> Play audio from an external file while viewing a video.